# Fetching data with dynamic routes in next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit

I'm new at next.js. I'm trying to create product page from catalog. In catalog page im receiving data from server:

```
// src/app/products/page.tsx
import React from "react";
import ProductsPageScene from "../../scenes/ProductsPageScene";

const getProducts = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(
            "https://impilomedicalsystems.co.za/wp-json/wp/v2/product"
        );

        return res.json();
    } catch (error: any) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
    }
};

const ProductsPage = async () => {
    const products: TProduct[] = await getProducts();

    return <ProductsPageScene products={products} />;
};

export default ProductsPage;
```

```
// src/scenes/ProductsPageScene/components/Products/index.tsx
import React, { FC, useState, useEffect } from "react";

import "swiper/css";
import "./index.css";

import { useAppSelector } from "@/app/store/store";

import { ProductItem } from "./ProductItem";

export const Products = () => {
    const filterStore = useAppSelector((state) => state.filter.filter);
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState<string | null>(filterStore);

    const products = useAppSelector((state) => state.products.products);

    useEffect(() => {
        setFilter(filterStore);
    }, [filterStore]);

    return (
        <div className="product w-full grid grid-cols-3 grid-rows-[auto] gap-[15px_18px] max-[1100px]:grid-cols-2 max-[700px]:grid-cols-1">
            {products.map(({ id, title, type }) => {
                id = Number(id);
                if (filter !== null) {
                    if (type === filter)
                        return <ProductItem key={id} id={id} title={title.rendered} />;
                } else return <ProductItem key={id} id={id} title={title.rendered} />;
            })}
        </div>
    );
};
```

When I'm visit product page from catalog, i see product info. But after reloading there's no product. I store products in redux and I know that after reloading store is resetting. My question is 'How can I fix this?'. Help please

Comment: Can you show what's in `ProductsPageScene`?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem!

Answer is to create file route.ts in folder called api.

Inside that file write:

```
export const GET = async (id?: number) => {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(
            `https://impilomedicalsystems.co.za/wp-json/wp/v2/product`
        );

        if (!res.ok) {
            // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
            throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
        }

        const products = await res.json();

        if (id) {
            const product = products.find((item: any) => item.id === id);
            return product;
        }

        return products;
    } catch (error: any) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
    }
};
```

And import that function inside a component!